# Why does the ellipse position not similar to my mouse position?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a code here that will add an ellipse and line when mouse is clicked.

```
class Viewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(leftImagePhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 451, 421))
        self.setSceneRect(20, 90, 451, 421)
```

I have an MouseRelase Event

```
   def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event): 
        pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        point = self._scene.addEllipse(self._size/2, self._size/2, 10, 10, QPen(Qt.black), QBrush(Qt.green))
        point.setPos(QPointF(pos.x(),pos.y()))
        self._scene.addLine(pos.x(),pos.y(), self.posprev.x(), self.posprev.y(), QPen(Qt.green))
```

When I clicked the line, its position is similar to the mouse positon, but the ellipse positon has few gap or difference to the exact mouse position.The center of the ellipse should be the endpoitn of the line or where the mouse position is.

See image here:

[image: here]

Can someone help me what is wrong why the ellipse will not add on the exact position to the mouse?

Comment: what are the parameters that the ellipse requires? some libraries use left corner, width, height  or center, and radius? Take a look at the documentation and you will know if you have to substract something to adjust the position

Comment: @Elle For future reference, please take screenshots with your computer, not with a camera.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of `addEllipse()` [explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addEllipse):

> Note that the item's geometry is provided in item coordinates, and its position is initialized to (0, 0).

This is actually valid for all QGraphicsScene functions that add basic shapes, and the initialized position is always `(0, 0)` for all QGraphicsItems in general.

Consider the following:

```
point = scene.addEllipse(5, 5, 10, 10)
```

The above will create an ellipse enclosed in a rectangle that starts at `(5, 5)` *relative to its position*. Since we've not moved it yet, that position is the origin point of the scene.

[image: creating the ellipse]

<sup>The ellipse as it as soon as it's created, with the rectangle shown as a reference of its boundaries.</sup>

Then, we set its position (assuming the mouse is at `20, 20` of the scene):

```
point.setPos(QPointF(20, 20))
```

The result will be an ellipse enclosed in a rectangle that has its top left corner at `(25, 25)`, which is the rectangle position relative to the item position: `(5, 5) + (20, 20)`.

[image: the ellipse is translated]

<sup>Note that the above shows *both* the ellipse in the original position *and* the result of `setPos()`.</sup>

If you want an ellipse that will be centered on its position, you must create one with *negative* x and y coordinates that are half of the width and height of its rectangle.

Considering the case above, the following will properly show the ellipse *centered* at `(20, 20)`:

```
point = scene.addEllipse(-5, -5, 10, 10)
point.setPos(QPointF(20, 20))
```

[image: the correct approach]

Notes:

- as the documentation shows, [`mapToScene()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene) already returns a QPointF, there's no point in doing `setPos(QPointF(pos.x(), pos.y()))`: just do `setPos(pos)`;
- remember what said above: all items have a starting position at `(0, 0)`; this is valid also for the line you're creating after that point, which will be drawn between `pos` and `self.posprev`, but will *still* be at `(0, 0)` in scene coordinates;
- the view and the scene might need mouse events, especially if you're going to add *movable* items; you should *always* call the base implementation (in your case, `super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)`) when you override functions, unless you *really* know what you're doing;
- as already suggested to you, it is of **utmost importance** that you read and understand the whole graphics view documentation, especially how its [coordinate system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system) works; the graphics view framework is as much powerful as it is complex, and cannot be learnt just by trial and error: being able to use it requires a lot of patience in understanding how it works by carefully studying the documentation of each of its classes and **all** functions you are going to use;