# How to draw an ellipse center at the exact mouse position?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to draw an ellipse where its center is in the exact point of the mouse position. My code works and draws the ellipse but its drawn shifted to the right from the mouse position. So I want to know how to make its center with the mouse. I have two classes one for the Ellipse object and one for the graphics scene. I draw an ellipse based on a certain flag and add it to the scene. The mouse move event just keeps track of the movement and updates the ellipse position.

```
class NodeEllipse(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    isPressed=False
    pozx=0
    pozy=0
    name=""
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self,posx,posy,r,color,name):
        super().__init__(0, 0,  r, r)
        self.setPos(posx,posy)
        self.pozx=posx
        self.pozy=posy
        self.name=name
        self.setRect(posx,posy,r,r)
        self.setBrush(color)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable)
        self.textItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(name, self)
        rect = self.textItem.boundingRect()
        rect.moveCenter(self.boundingRect().center())
        self.textItem.setPos(rect.topLeft())
      
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("i am pressed or not")
        print(self.isPressed)
        self.isPressed=True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        orig_cursor_position = event.lastScenePos()
        updated_cursor_position = event.scenePos()

        orig_position = self.scenePos()

        updated_cursor_x = updated_cursor_position.x() - orig_cursor_position.x() + 
        orig_position.x()
        updated_cursor_y = updated_cursor_position.y() - orig_cursor_position.y() + 
        orig_position.y()
        self.setPos(updated_cursor_x, updated_cursor_y)
        self.pozx=updated_cursor_x
        self.pozy=updated_cursor_y
        
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print("i am released")
        print('Node Release x: {0}, y: {1}'.format(self.pos().x(), self.pos().y()))   
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    existingBase=False
    baseBox=""
   
   
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        
        if(self.existingBase):
            pos = event.scenePos()
            posx=pos.x()
            posy=pos.y()
            print("orig pos mouse"+str(posx)+" "+str(posy))
            radius=44
            color=QBrush(Qt.green)
            myellipse=NodeEllipse(posx,posy,radius,color,self.baseBox)
            self.baseNodes.append(myellipse)
            self.addItem(myellipse)
            print(str(posx)+" "+str(posy))
```

Comment: Why are you overriding the mouse movement, while it already works just using the `ItemIsMovable` flag?

Comment: I can't mark it as duplicate, but see [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71703499/2001654). In short: what you want to do is to make the *origin point* (which will be its *position*) of the item its center, meaning that the item boundaries will have to be half-width above and half-height left of that origin. Change to `super().__init__(-r/2, -r/2, r, r)`, remove `setPos()` and `setRect()` (they were redundant anyway), and also the whole mouse event overrides, which, as said above, are unnecessary if you use the `ItemIsMovable` flag.